# Spring Data MongoDB query by id returns no result

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having trouble finding data with MongoDB. I can't query the data using the id.

This is my Entity:

```
@Document(language = "german", collection = "feature")
@ToString
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Feature {
    @Id private String id;
    private String name;
    private FeatureType type;
    private List<String> productIds;
    private Client client;
}
```

I'm querying the data like this:

```
mongoTemplate.find(query(where("_id").is(new ObjectId("60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930"))), Feature.class);
```

Either using ObjectId or just the id String doesn't work, I always get an empty array back. I have confirmed that the object with the id is in the database. It is no solution for me to just use the JPA method, because this is a more simple example for a custom query that does not work either.

Also, using `id` or `_id` both generates the same query (see third code listing), so replacing one with the other does not make any change

When I query the database directly using the outputted query it works though. The outputted query is the first one, I can't use `$oid` though, because it is an unknown operator, so I have to replace it with `new ObjectId`, resulting in the second query. According to [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId) it should make no difference though.

```
db.feature.find({"_id": {"$oid": "60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930"}});
db.feature.find({"_id": new ObjectId("60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930")});
```

Funnily, when I use `is` or `in` I get an empty array, when I use `ne` or `nin` I get all elements except the one with the given id.

```
mongoTemplate.find(query(where("_id").ne(new ObjectId("60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930"))), Feature.class);
```

Is this some mistake on my end or is there an error in the implementation of how the `is` method works? Does anyone have an idea?

#### Update:

Here is the document i expect from the database. I've had to replace the path of the class though.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930"},
    "_class": "<path>.Feature",
    "client": "CLIENTNAME",
    "name": "all products",
    "productIds": ["60c6f7f7f0708603ff37bc5a", ... , "60c6fba7f0708603ff38b5f4"],
    "type": "ALL"
  }
]
```

Comment: At a minimum, include a copy of the document retrieved from the database.

Comment: Spring automatically converts `id` to `_id` and everything annotated as `@Id` to `_id`. You don't need to pass `_id` to mongo template. Try running `mongoTemplate.find(query(where("id").is("60d0ae8d01aad528e2496930")), Feature.class)`

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic I've included the document I expect from the database.

Comment: @geobreze both versions don't work, they're resulting in the same query.